# Is there any way to avoid Navigation Drawer to be closed when clicked?

Tags: java, android, navigation

I'm working with the new Navigatino drawer from Google and I'm trying to use some sort of toggle buttons inside, but everytime I click on one of these buttons I cannot avoid the menu closing.

Is there any way to avoid that every click closes de navigation drawer?

Thanks!

Comment: please post what you did? i mean  your code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are able to lock the drawer in open state with:

```
drawerLayout.setDrawerLockMode(DrawerLayout.LOCK_MODE_LOCKED_OPEN);
```

and close & unlock with:

```
drawerLayout.setDrawerLockMode(DrawerLayout.LOCK_MODE_UNLOCKED);
drawerLayout.closeDrawer(drawerView);
```

Also the drawer shouldn't behave like you described, please edit your post and paste code + xml here.

[Link to documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/widget/DrawerLayout.html)